# where is the submit handler for the Drupal Commerce Review page?

Tags: commerce

I need to know how the drupal Commerce review page is being created and where the submit handler is which precedes that page. I have added a couple of fields which aren't being picked up in the panes, and I want to debug in the handler (or even a review page tpl file). Where can I find this? I have looking though the code and havn't found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All checkout page forms are built using the checkout pane info David Thomas indicated through the function commerce_checkout_form() in commerce_checkout.pages.inc. The validate handler does double duty for the checkout form, validating and actually submitting data on a pane by pane basis to capture valid data as soon as possible. This function is aptly named commerce_checkout_form_validate(). Your best bet will be to log debug messages using watchdog instead of displaying them on the screen via drupal_set_message(), because we do some status message processing in there to put messages inline with the panes that generated them - that can make it hard to force a debug message to show when you expect it.

Comment: So, if I want to add some functionality after the user clicks the submit button on the first checkout page, do I need to set new validate handler or a new submit handler?

Comment: You can do either one depending on when you need your code to be executed. Make it a validate handler prepended to the existing #validate array of the checkout form's submit button if it needs to go first or append it to the end or just add it to #submit array if it doesn't matter. Just make sure you're adding handlers to the button, not the form level #validate / #submit arrays - those are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add checkout panes to the review process you can use

[`hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info/DC)

In particular:

> **review**: boolean indicating whether or not the pane should be included
>   in the review checkout pane; defaults to TRUE

and also:

> **callbacks**: an array of callback function names for the various types
>   of callback required for all the checkout pane operations, arguments
>   per callback in parentheses: ....
>   **review**($form, $form_state,
>   $checkout_pane, $order): returns data used in the construction of the
>   Review checkout pane

If you want to alter existing checkout panes, e.g the form or the content on the review page, you can use

[`hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter/DC)

and adjust the `checkout_form` or `review` property there.